# minimum height for website

Tags: html, css

I like it when the adress bar disappears on my iphone when i visit a website. This can be done by a minimal height. I try to do this a proper way with css.

If i use this, then it goes fine, except i don't find this friendly for other phones (the value is a bit extreme now..):

```
body {
    min-height: 9000px;
}
```

If i use this, then it doesn't work.

```
body {
    min-height: max-device-height;
}
```

what is a good way to deal with this problem?

Comment: `html,body{height:100%;min-height:100%;height:auto;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use this javascript:

```
var height = screen.availHeight;
element.style.setAttribute("min-height",  height + 'px', false);
```

for element u have to use the element u want to set of course...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-device-height`, but only in media queries, like this:

```css
  @media only screen and (max-device-height: 500px) {
    min-height: 500px;
  }
```

(more examples here: https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/)

It will however take a lot of rules to do this for all phones.

I think it's better to try to set `html, body {min-height: 100%;}`. That rule will try to make  the min-height 100% of the window height. Possibly, the address bar only disappears if the size is larger than the normal viewport. In that case, you may need a value that is a little larger, like 101% or maybe 110%, which is certainly less extreme than 9000px.